# rpm installation error: Header V4 RSA/SHA1 signature: BAD, key ID

Tags: key, package, rpm, signature, gnupg

When installing on CentOS 5/Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 5.6/SuSE 11.2 systems, the packages I created and signed fail with the following error:

> Header V4 RSA/SHA1 signature: BAD, key ID a2051fc7

An "rpm -qip " and "rpm -v --checksig " yield the same error.

An "rpm -qip " and "rpm -v --checksig " on the signing machine shows everything to be "OK".

What am I missing?  The key was generated on an Ubuntu system.  Could that be an issue?

On the installing machine, an "rpm --import " was done.  A "gpg --import" was also done. An "rpm -qi gpg-pubkey*" as well as a "gpg --list-keys" both show that the key was installed.

On the signing machine, in the ~/.rpmmacros is the following:

```
%_signature gpg
%_gpg_path /root/.gnupg
%_gpg_name Stealth Seeker <support@stealthseeker.com>
%__gpg /usr/bin/gpg
%__gpg_sign_cmd %{__gpg} \
 gpg --force-v3-sigs --digest-algo=sha1 --batch --no-verbose --no-armor \
 --passphrase-fd 3 --no-secmem-warning -u "%{_gpg_name}" \
 -sbo %{__signature_filename} %{__plaintext_filename}
```

The command used to sign is "rpm --resign *.rpm".  A list of what keys I have on the signing system are as follows:

```
# gpg --list-keys
/root/.gnupg/pubring.gpg
------------------------
pub   2048R/D2051F97 2014-05-06
uid                  Stealth Seeker <support@stealthseeker.com>
sub   2048R/DE308A91 2014-05-06

# gpg --list-secret-keys
/root/.gnupg/secring.gpg
------------------------
sec   2048R/D2051F97 2014-05-06
uid                  Stealth Seeker <support@stealthseeker.com>
ssb   2048R/DE308A91 2014-05-06
```

Comment: what version of RedHat machines does it work on? I don't believe V4 signatures work on CentOS 5 era machines so I'm not sure how it would work on similarly aged RedHat machines. I believe you need to force V3 signatures for use with machines with rpm of that age.

Comment: That macro content is where? On the signing machine? Can you put it in the question so you can format it correctly? Does the gpg key file that you imported have only one key in it or more than one (including subkeys)?

Comment: I just imported public/private keys to a RELS release 5.6 system, the above .rpmmacros file, and tried to sign an rpm (verison 4.4.23).  The "rpm -resign *.rpm" gave a "gpg: WARNING: standard input reopened" which according to the internet is a non-issue.  However, an "rpm -qip *rpm" gave the same error, **"Header V3 RSA/SHA1 signature: BAD, key ID d2051f97."**  Darn it.

Comment: That's not the same error (note the `V3` in there) but that means the key may in fact be missing or not installed correctly. Does the key file have more than one key in it (including sub-keys)?

Comment: Other than "gpg --{list-keys,list-secret-keys}", I don't know how to see if there are sub keys. Physically looking at the exported private and public key files, there's only one (1) key block per file.  The results of the two gpg commands are listed in the above text.  The command used to create the key was "gpg --gen-key", use RSA, use 2048-bit, and use a passphrase.

Answer (score 2):

I believe that `sub` key in the output is the problem here.

I believe you are hitting [this known RPM bug](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=436812) with importing a file with multiple gpg keys.

Unfortunately gpg does not make sorting this out easy (since you can't export without sub-keys) and rpm does not make working around this (or really even seeing the problem) possible since it doesn't know it is getting it wrong and you can't get it to give you the information you would need to confirm the problem.

If you export just the primary key from your keyring (without the sub-key) and try importing and signing/verifying with that I believe it will work.

Comment: After doing a quick google search on "export primary gpg key", I was unable to find anything other than, "gpg --export -a KEY_ID > MYORG-GPG-KEY.public", which is what I've done.  Do you have a page which shows how to export the only the primary key?  Or the flag I should be using to export the primary key?

Comment: @user2569618 I left that information out because I also didn't have a good method of doing that. When I was doing my testing with this (when we ran into similar issues at work). I was forced to copy the keyring and manually delete the sub-key before exporting the key for testing. (I wrote scripts to handle all of the work for me as I was testing many key types and sizes but that's the work that was being done.)

Comment: @user2569618 Alternatively, if you just want to test this (and/or aren't wedded to your current key) you could try recreating the gpg key being sure to select whatever the option for RSA 'signing only' is (instead of RSA+RSA or whatever).